# Iterating through linq results results in more items than query count

Tags: c#, linq

I'm fairly new to LINQ but this seemed pretty straightforward.

I have an XML doc which contains a structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<folders>
  <folder id="-1" parent="-100">
    <name><![CDATA[Root]]></name>
    <children>
      <folder id="2" parent="-1">
        <name><![CDATA[Contribution]]></name>
        <documents />
        <children>
          <folder id="775" parent="2">
            <name><![CDATA[category1]]></name>
            <documents />
            <children>
              <folder id="2319" parent="775">
                <name><![CDATA[Acad_Depts1]]></name>
                <documents />
                <children>
                  <folder id="26965" parent="2319">
                    <name><![CDATA[Student1]]></name>
                    <documents>
                      <document>
                      </document>
                    </documents>
                  </folder
                </children>
              </folder>
              <folder id="2319" parent="775">
                <name><![CDATA[Acad_Depts2]]></name>
                <documents />
                <children>
                  <folder id="26965" parent="2319">
                    <name><![CDATA[Student1]]></name>
                    <documents>
                      <document>
                      </document>
                    </documents>
                  </folder
                </children>
              </folder>
              etc...
            </children>
          </folder>
        </children>
      </folder>
    </children>
  </folder>
</folders>
```

What I'm trying to do is to select all the  elements with an attribute 'parent="775"'.

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("folders_only_registrar_folder.xml");
IEnumerable <XElement> folders = xelement.Elements();

var query = from node in folders.Descendants("folder")
            where node.Attribute("parent").Value == registrarNodeID
            select node;

Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
Console.ReadKey();

foreach(XElement departmentNode in query.Descendants("name"))
{
          Console.WriteLine(departmentNode.Value.ToString());
}
```

When I run the query and test the count, I get 48 results (which is good)... but when I try to write out those same nodes, I get hundreds of results.  For some reason it's giving me almost ALL of the elements named "folder" including children folders.

Thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE... ok so now I know why i'm getting all the folders but any thoughts on how to create a collection of each grouping of nodes and sub-nodes?

Can the selection in LINQ send each 775 folder node (plus it's collective sub-nodes) into some sort of collection of nodes and then I could parse through them in a foreach by grouping of node?

Comment: `where node.Attribute("parent").Value == registrarNodeID` is not taken into consideration in your for each loop

Comment: If you want the immediate name node of each folder node with that parent attribute value then you need to select them `select node.Element("name")`

Comment: @preciousbetine yes i'm realizing that now also ... i guess what i was hoping to do was to create a collection of 'folder' (plus it's children) nodes so that I could iterate through them... each folder node with a parent attribute of 775 is in essence a Department collection of document details.  I need to be able to parse each of these departments on their own, dealing with the specific documents under them as needed.

Any suggestions for a better process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `query.Descendants()` with just `query`. `query.Descendants()` gets every child of every node that was originally contained within `query`.

Comment: Thanks!  That definitely helped... had to add some additional filtering in the console.writeline in that loop but I'm getting my 48 results now.  Thanks for the keen eye!!